# Programmatically add v-on directives to DOM elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
<span @click="showModal = $event.target.innerHtml>Tag 1</span>
<span @click="showModal = $event.target.innerHtml>Tag 2</span>
<span @click="showModal = $event.target.innerHtml>Tag 3</span>
```

Clicking in any of the 3 spans will make `this.showModal` to have the value of each of the span content elements. But this code looks repetitive and unnecessary. I know I can create a component with v-for and have the data for the span contents somewhere else, but I want to know how to do this for very specific reasons. I'd like to have this:

```
<span>Tag 1</span>
<span>Tag 2</span>
<span>Tag 3</span>
```

And a function, e.g. in the hook `mounted()` of the component, that adds the v-on directive for `click` to each one of them.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: uses `custom directive` will be one option.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
<template>
    <span v-for="tag in tags" @click="showModal(tag)" v-text="tag"></span>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                tags: ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2', 'Tag 3']
            }
        },
        methods: {
            showModal(tag) {
                console.log("Showing modal for tag:", tag)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @mtflud!
However, it's of paramount importance that the HTML exists as it is, for me. Precisely in my question I said I could do it with a v-for and the data somewhere else. I need the HTML to hold the content. However your answer might help someone who wants to do the same thing without my constraint.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I really can't think of a cleaner way to do that preserving the HTML tags than what @dr_barto 's answer says.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method which is called on clicks that reads the element's HTML content.

The template:

```
<span @click="doStuff">Tag 1</span>
<span @click="doStuff">Tag 2</span>
<span @click="doStuff">Tag 3</span>
```

The method:

```
doStuff(e) {
  this.showModal = e.target.innerHTML
}
```

Comment: Yes, actually that's the next thing I've done already, you were fast!
However I'm actually talking about 36 elements (in my original code)... I guess if I want to have the data in the HTML, I have no other option :(

Comment: I can't think of a more concise way to do this in Vue; if you were to fall back to raw JS you could of course use DOM APIs to programmatically attach a `click` event handler to each `span`, but I would avoid that.

Comment: What's the reason to preserve every HTML tag? I imagine its something related to indexing? If so, adding the tags with JS won't do it, you would need to add them from your backend.

Comment: My example is very much simplified for the purposes of the question only, but the title sums up the question, trying to rephrase better it would be: "Can I add a vue v-on directive to an DOM element inside a component template IMPERATIVELY instead of DECLARATIVELY?"
I know this goes against the declarative nature of Vue (how it should be!) but I wanted to know if it was possible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a method to call when the tag is clicked and pass the id of the tag that was clicked through to handle appropriately.

Assuming that you have an array of the tag text:

```
data: function() {
  return {
    tagTotal: ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2', 'Tag 3'];
  }
}
```

Then in the HTML section:

```
<span v-for="tag in tagTotal" @click="methodToCall(tag)">
  {{ tag }}
</span>
```

Then in your mounted, methods, or created section you could add:

```
mounted: {
  methodToCall: function(tag) {
    showModal = tag;
    // or 'this.showModal = tag' if showModal is a part of the componenet.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If direct-process Dom elements, [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#ad) will be one option.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

let vMyDirective = {}
vMyDirective.install = function install (_Vue) {
  _Vue.directive('my-directive', {
    inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        _Vue.set(vnode.context, binding.value.model, el.innerHTML)
      }, false)
    }
  })
}

Vue.use(vMyDirective)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testValues: ['label a', 'label b'],
      showModal: 'nothing!!!'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>showModal: {{showModal}}</h2>
  <div>
    <p v-for="(item, index) in testValues" v-my-directive="{'model': 'showModal'}">Test:<span>{{item}}</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally added the listeners manually with vanilla js, in order to save code:

```
mounted: function() {
    let spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

    spans.forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('click', this.clickTag);
    })
}
methods: {
    clickTag(event) { this.showModal = event.target.innerHTML }
}
```

It's important not using an arrow function for `mounted` because otherwise it won't bind the vue instance for `this`.

Thanks for your answers.